# Is there a way to transfer data from Google Cloud Storage to Azure Blob Storage using GCP resources?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, azure-blob-storage

I want to move csv files from Google Cloud storage into Azure Blob storage. I am aware that it can be achieved using Azure Data Factory. I wanted the movement to be initiated and billed on the Google Cloud side rather than Azure's side(using Azure Data Factory), i.e. The data push should be initiated from the GCP side rather than a pull from Azure's side.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward and reliable way as you mentioned is by using Azure Data Factory, GCP doesn't offer any tool to move the data to another service provider.

A codeless option could be use a Compute engine VM with [Azure Fuse Storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse), [GCP Fuse storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) and using `rsync` command to copy the content from GCP to AZure

```
[GCP Bucket] ----- Fuse Storage --- > [GCE VM] ---- Fuse Storage ---> [Azure]
```

The GCE VM needs to be in the same region than the bucket to improve latency and avoid egress traffic fee, with this option you only will be billed by the [network egress](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-buckets) of Cloud storage and for the [VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing).

In both cases, Cloud Storage and Blob storage not generate any charge related to ingress traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use azcopy tool like below:

```
azcopy cp --recursive=true "<-source url->" "<-destination url->"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done programmatically. You can write a GKE microservice to move data from cloud storage to azure blob storage -

https://medium.com/@irena-sayv/transfer-file-from-google-cloud-storage-to-azure-blob-storage-programmatically-25f9d5905b61